# visual studio 2015 sublime theme

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2015, sublimetext3

Is there Sublime theme for Visual Studio 2015?

For example for [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) .

Themes from [Studio Styles](https://studiostyl.es/) not correct working with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The default color scheme of Sublime Text is [Monokai](http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/07/15/textmate-color-theme/) by Wimer Hazenberg and I bet there are several attempts of porting it to Visual Studio. I'm not sure whether there's a full theme, since Sublime Text has very little of a UI that could be ported.

Here are several that I found online:

1. You can build Monokai (and other) color schemes for Visual Studio using [base16-builder](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-builder)
2. There's a Monokai port for download at [Studio Styles](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/monokai)
3. …and several others available on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=monokai%20visual%20studio)

Comment: 1. The base16-builder template seems to use VS 2010 elements, which I think aren't fully compatible with VS 2015.
2. Studio Styles unfortunately doesn't support VS 2015, so I'm unsure about the results from here. In both these cases, I think elements may not get the colors as intended by the theme.