# Any Way to install/import sublime/vscode color theme for visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015, vs-color-theme-editor

I am actually trying to get one color theme that I use in VS-Code for VS2015. But the theme is for sublime-text/atom. I can't find that color-theme for visual studio 2015.

> I found this question here
>   ***[visual studio 2015 sublime theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828550/visual-studio-2015-sublime-theme)***

**Is there any way to install or import vs-code extension to visual studio 2015 ?**

Comment: Oddly enough, themes designed for one application usually won't work with another application.  Because they're completely different applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no ways to convert between the two theme formats. Visual Studio uses a proprietary theme style as [shown here](https://github.com/PeteW/VisualStudioThemes/blob/master/Vs2012/BlueYellow.vstheme), whereas Visual Studio Code uses textmate themes as [shown here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-monokai-dimmed/themes/dimmed-monokai.tmTheme)

Visual Studio Format:

```
  <Color Name="CSS String Value">
    <Background Type="CT_AUTOMATIC" Source="00000000" />
    <Foreground Type="CT_RAW" Source="FFD69D85" />
  </Color>
  <Color Name="HTML Attribute">
    <Background Type="CT_AUTOMATIC" Source="00000000" />
    <Foreground Type="CT_RAW" Source="FF9CDCFE" />
  </Color>
```

Visual Studio Code

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tag Inline Source</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.tag.inline source, text.html.php.source</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>
            </string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#9AA83A</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tag Other</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.tag.other, entity.name.tag.style, entity.name.tag.script, meta.tag.block.script, source.js.embedded punctuation.definition.tag.html, source.css.embedded punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>
            </string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#9872A2</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tag Attribute</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>entity.other.attribute-name, meta.tag punctuation.definition.string</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>
            </string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#D0B344</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

As you can see, they are very different formats, and unfortunately there aren't tools for converting between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Textmate `.tmtheme` file, like the ones used for themes in Sublime Text, then you can convert that to a VSCode theme extension using the `yo code` tool as described in the documentation: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/themes/#adding-a-new-theme

Basically, you need `npm` installed.

Place the `.tmtheme` file somewhere accessible from your terminal and do:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
yo code
```

Follow the prompts, specifying the full file path of the theme file.

Place the resulting extension folder into `%vs_code_dir%/extensions/` and restart VSCode before using your new theme.